# How best to store a 512 bit Data object in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to store a 512 bit data in mysql.

I'm wondering if it is better to store it as **char(64)** or 8 columns of **bigint** or something else?

My priority is to maximize the speed of comparison (I am ok to have slow updates, inserts, deletes in exchange for a faster comparison speed)

(I am aware simply storing it as char(64) will probably take the least development time, however although that's very important, it's currently ranked last in my set of priorities)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028949/mysql-ideal-field-type-for-fixed-width-binary-data

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your downvotes, I've just read some Daily WTF, so this is going to be a bit crazy answer...

Store however you like (char, bigints..) but also add a hashed(md5? part of md5?) value, then after select, filter out false positives.

Comment: the 512 bit is actually a SHA-512 hash result.

Answer (score 0):

you probably should **not** use `char`;  character types apply encoding rules to the data, which make perfect sense when the data is text, but don't work at all for binary data.  you should use [`binary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)